# Как через метод Count подсчитать идущее подряд количество символов

Tags: c#, linq

Надо подсчитать количество символов идущих подряд.
Если 2 подряд идущих символов находятся вначале строки то выводить 1
Если 2 подряд идущих символов находятся в конце строки, то выводить 1

Примеры вывода и ввода

```
+-+-+-
0
++-+--+-+-+
1
-+-++--
1
+-++-+-+-+
2
+++
3
---
3
```

Я попытался разбить строку на массив символов и через них как-то искать эти условия, но получается какая-то длинная пелена. Можно ли как-то решить эту задачу с помощью метода Count Linq?

```
 public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var d = Console.ReadLine().ToArray();
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < d.Length; i++) 
            {
                if (d[0] == '+' && d[1] == '+') 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(1);
                    break;
                }
                else if (d[i] == '+') 
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            
            
    
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Я попытался разбить строку на массив символов` - строка это и есть массив символов, и работать с ней изначально можно как с массивом символов, разница только в том, что нельзя символы менять, а читать можно точно так же как с массива. Зачем массив разбивать на массив? Ну а если вам нужен именно массив с возможностью перезаписи, то есть более эффективный метод `.ToCharArray()`.

Comment: Задача без костылей решается с использованием простого шаблона проектирования "Конечный автомат". Изучите его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while (true)
 {
     String str = Console.ReadLine();
     Int32 indexSymbol = 0, indexFirstSymbol = 0, indexLastSymbol = str.Length - 1;
     Int32 limitCounterSymbols = 2; // Количество контроля 1-ый или полсдений символов
     Int32 count = 1 // Количество символов в средине строки
         , maxCount = 0;
     Boolean checkFirstSymbol = true, checkLastSymbol = true;

     for (Int32 i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
     {
         if (checkFirstSymbol && indexFirstSymbol != i && str[indexFirstSymbol] != str[i])
         {
             Int32 tmpCount = i - 1 == limitCounterSymbols ? i - 2 : i - 1;
             maxCount = tmpCount > maxCount ? tmpCount : maxCount;
             checkFirstSymbol = false;
             if (i == limitCounterSymbols)
             {
                 break;
             }
         }
         if (checkLastSymbol && indexLastSymbol != i && str[indexLastSymbol] != str[str.Length - 1 - i])
         {
             Int32 tmpCount = str.Length - (str.Length - i + 1);
             tmpCount = tmpCount == limitCounterSymbols ? tmpCount - 1 : tmpCount;
             maxCount = tmpCount > maxCount ? tmpCount : maxCount;
             checkLastSymbol = false;
             if (str.Length - (str.Length - i) == limitCounterSymbols)
             {
                 break;
             }
          }
             if (i != indexSymbol && str[i] == str[indexSymbol])
             {
                 count++;
             }
             if (str[i] != str[indexSymbol] || i + 1 == str.Length)
             {
                 maxCount = count > 1 && count > maxCount ? count : maxCount;
                 count = 1;
                 indexSymbol = i;
             }
             }
            Console.WriteLine(maxCount);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: правда вот этот тест у меня не проходит ваш код 

++-+--+-+-+ 
1

Comment: Проходит, максимум подряд идущих подряд символов 2шт.

Comment: У вас в примере +++ = 3шт., а в ++-+--+-+-+ = 1 шт. Так какой верный?

Comment: Если идет 2 подряд в начале, то выводится 1, если больше 2 подряд вначале, то выводится количество идущих символов, в конце такое же правило

Comment: Да, не дочитал, а если в средине 2 или 3 символа подряд, что приоритетней? ++---++

Comment: в середине не важно, главное чтоб вначале и вконце не было 2 подряд идущих символов, в середине если есть, то они просто подсчитываются и выводится результат их количества